# How do I run a shell / bash command in fabric

Tags: bash, shell, fabric

I am trying to convert a bash script file into fabric. I tried copying line by line from the .sh file into fabric file and it works, until I encounter this road block

```
cat > /root/fcgi.py << DELIM
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pylint: disable=W0622

.....

DELIM
```

It works well in the .sh file but then it does not work in fabric run commands. Any suggestion how can I do it in a the fabric way?

Comment: Heredoc can be easily converted to an `echo` (just not as elegant).

Comment: Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents.

Comment: you mean "echo cat > /root/fcgi.py <<DELIM

Comment: Do you know what `echo` does? I obviously meant `echo "content of the python script" >/root/fcgi.py`.